# How do I get all of the values from a GWT multiselect ListBox on a post?

Tags: python, django, gwt, post, listbox

I have a multiselect ListBox in a FormPanel in GWT. I have set the name of the listbox to "foo" via ListBox.setName(). When I post the form, I see that all of the selected values get posted, but all are bound to the same name "foo". So I seemingly cannot get each of the posted values (I am using Django/Python server-side to handle the post). When I access params['foo'] in Django, I only pick up the last posted value.

How do I get to all of the values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `params.getlist('foo')`.

See the [documentation for QueryDict objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects).